# Making \cpageref output commas instead of "and"

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, comma-separated-list

I can use `\cpageref` to output a list of page references. For example, the markup:

```
You should check \cpageref{sec:section1,sec:section2,sec:section3}.
```

... renders as:

```
You should check pages 3, 5 and 7.
```

However, what I need in a specific case is the output to be:

```
You should check pages 3, 5, 7.
```

Do I have any way to tell `\cpageref` to always use commas and not "and"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need this behavior all over the document, simply add the following line in your preamble

```
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,\nobreakspace}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,\nobreakspace}

\begin{document}

\section{First}\label{sec:section1}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Second}\label{sec:section2}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Third}\label{sec:section3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\bigskip

You should check \cpageref{sec:section1,sec:section2,sec:section3}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Otherwise, if you only need it in a specific place, use

```
{\renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,\nobreakspace}\cpageref{sec:section1,sec:section2,sec:section3}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort]{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{First}\label{sec:section1}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Second}\label{sec:section2}
\lipsum[1-5]

\section{Third}\label{sec:section3}
\lipsum[1-5]

\bigskip

You should check \cpageref{sec:section1,sec:section2,sec:section3}.

And now check again 
{\renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,\nobreakspace}\cpageref{sec:section1,sec:section2,sec:section3}}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: One can also do `{\renewcommand{\creflastconjunction}{,~}\cpageref{...}}` if the final comma is wanted only in a specific place, which seems what the OP wants.